# Handling file not found on ftl page in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

How can we handle the file not found exception on fileName.ftl file? So many have explained handling it on the action servlets. But I am not using any action servlet to load the freemarker. So no other option and I have to find a way to handle it on the template file itself..!

Answer (score 2):

If the `FileNotFoundException` occurs during a FTL `<#import>` or `<#include>` inside your "main" FTL template, then I think you can catch the exception with FTL's [attempt-recover](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_attempt.html)-construct (similar to Java's `try-catch`). But if your "main" template cannot be found, then something outside of FreeMarker (e.g. the servlet which invoked FreeMarker) has to deal with it.